# Is it possible to deploy a node in a corda network that already contains bootstrapped nodes?

Tags: corda

Let us assume that there is a corda network. The network already has x number of nodes. All of these nodes are bootstrapped before deployment.

If I configure a new node, bootstrap it and deploy,

will the new node be able to identify and communicate with already existing peer nodes in the network ? 
will the new node be identified and reached out by the peer nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios:

**All the nodes are running on the same machine**

- Shut down all the nodes
- Move all the node directories into the same parent directory
- Create the new node's `node.conf` file in the same parent directory
- Run the bootstrapper. This will:

  - Create the node directory for the new node
  - Have copied the node's info to all the existing node directories
- Restart the nodes

**All the nodes are running on separate machines**

As of Corda 3.1, you can't bootstrap a network across different machines. In the future, the bootstrapper may be extended to bootstrap across machines via SSH.

For now, you have to:

- Deploy the new node on its machine
- Start the node with the `--just-generate-node-info` flag

  - This will generate the node's `nodeInfo-*` file in the node's base directory
- Shut down all the nodes
- Copy the new node's `nodeInfo-*` file to the `additional-node-infos` folder of all the existing nodes
- Copy the *entire* contents of the `additional-node-infos` folder of an existing node into the new node's `additional-node-infos` folder
- Restart the nodes

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to the nodeinfos, there is also a network-parameters file that needs to copied over to the new node. Ow, the new node might not know the notaries.

\Sean